# Why this error arising? users.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, axios

I am trying to render names from a API with Axios. Even I can see all data in console but unable to render as it shows error:

> users.map is not a function

Below I'm sharing my code of the file. I'm quite new that might be the reason I'm unable to figure it out.

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import { Container, Table} from "react-bootstrap";
import axios from 'axios';

class App extends React.Component {
    state = {
        users: [],
    };

    componentDidMount () {
        axios.get('https://5w05g4ddb1.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/dev/profile/listAll')
            .then(response => {
                const users = response.data;
                this.setState({ users });
                console.log(this.state.users);
            })
    }

    render() {
        const { users } = this.state;
        return (
        <div className="App">
              <Container fluid>
                  <Table striped bordered hover size="sm">
                      <thead>
                      <tr>
                          <th><div id="">Image</div></th>
                          <th>Name</th>
                          <th>Gender</th>
                          <th>Age</th>
                          <th>Date</th>
                          <th>Status</th>
                      </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>

                      <tr>
                          { users.map(user => { return <td key={user.id}>{ user.name }</td> }) }

                      </tr>
                      </tbody>
                  </Table>
              </Container>
        </div>
      )
}
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Because the response from your request is an object, not an array. It looks like you need to set the state to the `list` property of the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response you are getting is not an array, but an object like this:

```
{"list":[{"id":"MnJJA0dbuw","name":"Anand Sharma","img":"https://incablet-tests.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/conference-content/photos/sponsors/Anand.jpeg","gender":"m","age":46,"date":"23/11/2019","status":"onboarded"}]}
```

You can access the array by replacing `const users = response.data;` with `const users = response.data.list;`

Comment: Incorrect. `response.data` is to reach the  data in the axios response, then you access the list item in the response object.

Answer (score 1):

In your axios get, in the “then” part change the line:

```
const users = response.data;
```

To:

```
const users = response.data.list;
```

Answer (score 0):

fast hack

```
{users.list.map(user => { return <td key={user.id}>{ user.name }</td> }) }
```

Answer (score -1):

There are 2 errors:

1. the response from api is not a list but an object, u need to go to response.list to use the list from the response
   it should be

```js
const users = response.data.list
```

2. your

```js
this.setState({users})
```

,you will need to change it to

```js
this.setState({users:<VARIABLE_NAME_TO_HOLD_USER_DATA>})
```

even what you write is valid like in ES6, that is somehow a bad idea, it is not a clear what are you doing, just define what u want to copy to ur component state

Comment: thanks @GabrielPetersson, i just knew it, just edited my answer